# How to refresh CheckboxTableViewer after adding an element?

Tags: eclipse, jface

Can somebody help me how do I refresh CheckboxTableViewer after added one element?

Please provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Viewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/Viewer.html).`refresh()` or [`AbstractTableViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/AbstractTableViewer.html).`add()` or any of the overloads.

Please read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) that explains the usage of Eclipse JFace TableViewer including label and content provider.

Comment: I have done this.It is not refreshing the checkBoxtableviewer.
Do i need to pass this viewer into Node class?

Comment: Here is my code


             DataRootNode rootNode = new DataRootNode (Data);
   dataViewer.setInput(rootNode);
Now i am adding one more data into my dataviewer
So how should i do it
??

Comment: @mum I added a link to my answer that you should read to understand the basics of JFace viewers.